# Crimp connectors making process review

Tags: connector, cables, wire

I'm actually working on a project with several "little" modules. They are all connected to the PSU and the MCU. So I've design interface for each, so I can easily wire everything together.

For that I've bought a full range of crimp connectors, male/female pins and 10wires cables. (the "biggest" interface use 9 wires + VDC/GND, but for VDC/GND I use biggest gauge and other connectors)

The problem is that I'm not sure of the way I'm building these cables. Here are the steps I go through with a 1 pin connector.

First I cut the cable so the insulator is near the beginning of the connector and the end of the wire touch the start of the pin :

[image]

Then I apply a bit of solder on the inside of the connector and cut the two little piece of metal at the base, without that I can't put the housing (this one is a previously made one where I've removed the housing, that's why he looks really ugly)

[image]

Then I place the housing and use to pliers to put it in place. (Can't put it manually)

[image]

[image]

And here's the final result :

[image]

What I don't like is :

- I need to cut a part of the base to insert the housing.
- I need to use pliers to insert the housing. But if I take a look at the housing there's a kind of little piece of plastic that should block the housing to move back once in place.
- If I force a bit I can remove the housing.

So do you have any advice's ? Does it sound ok for you ? (I'm just a hobbyist, it's not for a professional purpose or anything really "serious" or consumer related)

Comment: Three issues here. Solder in excess makes the contact body too large to fit into the housing. Soldering also makes a sharp transition zone from the wire to the joint inviting the wire to crack off with even a small amount of flexure. The insulation is meant to be placed into the rear most tines of the contact to provide strain relief for the wire joint. Stop soldering and crimp the contacts.

Comment: continued - Note that there are 100s of different contact designs from all the manufacturers and it takes a bevy of tools to support all the different types. You can find some general purpose tools that will support an assortment of medium sized contacts in the 18 to 26 AWG wire size range. Smaller contacts will almost certainly require a specialty tool for each contact family from the manfacturer. These tools can be relatively costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soldering will do the job but normally these are intended to be assembled using a [crimping tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimp_%28joining%29) that fastens the wire on the pin.

[image]

Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-pTsccCizA)

Comment: Yes I've got one of these but I can't figure out how to use it for that kind of cases, do I need a special one ?

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace  I have added a video link

Comment: Even though it's for a different connector type, I find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8Mfvv1PqpY) provides a better commentary (I get no sound on the one in the answer)

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace, you will need a specific crimp tool unless very lucky. The more common crimps can have multiple sources of crimp tools but for production quantity the makers tool is best.

Answer (score 0):

You are making one big mistake. The outermost crimp should cover the insulation, not bare wire. See the photograph on [this page (molex.com)](http://www.molex.com/molex/news/display_news.jsp?channel=News%20In%20Brief&channelId=-8&oid=993). The idea is that this prevent the bare wire from bending, reducing the chances of breaking the wire from metal fatigue.

Soldering is optional. It seems that soldering stranded wire will actually make it more brittle at the point where the solder ends. However, again with the outer crimp holding the insulation, this should not be an issue.